# Creating the ER Model after the creation fo the database

Tags: database, entity-relationship

I've created a program runnning on the web (html) about booking tickets on a cinema theater.

I now want to create its ER Model.

As far as I know, the logical sequence of actions is:

1. Create the ER Model
2. Generate the Physical Model
3. Create your Database

So now, when I try to create the ER model, the relation between my entities doesn't seem right. On the other hand, if I add more entities like customer or admin, then that means that I have created more tables for my database that I don't need.

Anyone can help me in this one?

Comment: Not sure what answer you're looking for here. Also if you add entities, what do you mean by "created more tables for your DB than you need"? If you have new entities shouldn't you have more tables? What's the actual question?

Comment: i wanted to upload an image but this site's politics of reputation....won't even refer to it. I mean that my entities may not be able to connect (relationship) between them so i may need more entities (for the model). But if i add more entities, so the model to have some kind of logic, that means i must change my actual DB by adding more tables